# How to get Asset URL when using PHPhotoLibrary to save image and video?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, phasset, phphotolibrary

My code used `ALAssetsLibrary` to save image and video to iOS gallery. But Xcode tells me that `ALAssetsLibrary` is deprecated as of iOS 9.0, and advise me to use `PHPhotoLibrary` instead.

With the old `ALAssetsLibrary`, I get an Asset URL after saving, something like `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=XXX`. But with `ALAssetsLibrary`, I find no easy way to get the asset URL back. A lot of relevant questions on SO refer to this code:

https://gist.github.com/jVirus/2f041bb8b1936093773f0bde42af3a49

But the URL returned is file URL: `file://path/to/file`, not the asset URL.

The best option I find is to get Asset Identifier and concatenate String:

```
return URL(string: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id="+assetId+"&ext=JPG")
```

This is an unsafe hack, as the URL format may change in the future. And sometimes I found the Asset Identifier includes "/" segments at the end, that need to be stripped away before concatenation.

Is there any 'official' API method to get the Asset URL of a `PHAsset`?

Comment: Just curious. what do you want to do with the asset URL? (the one `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=XXX`)

Comment: @HSG  Some SDKs require Asset URLs, like Facebook and Twitter SDK.

Comment: So maybe you want to get the image url to share, can see if https://gist.github.com/dddnuts/ede04e65193d5df6f5b901c004adc7c3 works for you? the code to get a sharable url of an assets